# Upper constraints for nls parameters

Tags: r, nls

I have the following code to fit a sigmoidal function to my data:

```
nlsLM(mepAMP ~ plateau / (1 + exp(slope*(S50 - pMSO))), 
      data = df,
      start = list(plateau = 7, S50 = 100, slope = 0.15)
```

From my understanding, `nlsLM` (much like base `nls` available in r) has the option of selecting upper and lower bounds for the data. I'd specifically like to constrain the `plateau` to ≤8 mV to provide a physiologically plausible approximation of that parameter. Is there a way to constrain just one parameter? I've seen some posts where they specify `upper = c(1000, 1)` or something along those lines, but I'm not sure if that constrains all parameters and how I could specify `plateau`.

I've tried `upper = c(8)`, but that gives me the following error:

```
Error in nls.lm(par = start, fn = FCT, jac = jac, control = control, lower = lower,  : 
  length(upper) must be equal to length(par)
```

I can't seem to find the proper syntax for setting the upper bound and would appreciate any guidance.

**EDIT:**

Thank you Allan for your help. I included `upper = c(plateau = 8, S50 = Inf, slope = Inf)` when I have multiple subjects, however, this seems to change not only the model fits where the plateau *did* go over 8, but also those that were nowhere close to that. Is this normal? I would think that it wouldn't touch the model fitting for those whose plateau was already below the constraint.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a named vector. The vector must contain upper limits for all the parameters. If you only want to set an upper parameter on one of the values, set the others to `Inf`

```r
library(minpack.lm)

nlsLM(mepAMP ~ plateau / (1 + exp(slope*(S50 - state))), 
                         data = df, 
                         start = list(plateau = 1, S50 = 1, slope = 1),
                         upper = c(plateau = 3, S50 = Inf, slope = Inf)) 
#> Nonlinear regression model
#>   model: mepAMP ~ plateau/(1 + exp(slope * (S50 - state)))
#>    data: df
#> plateau     S50   slope 
#>   3.000   5.912   1.014 
#>  residual sum-of-squares: 1.259
#> 
#> Number of iterations to convergence: 13 
#> Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.49e-08
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data used - taken from previous question**

```r
df <- structure(list(mepAMP = c(0.38117575, 0.11300747, 0.37239499, 
0.51321839, 0.56851893, 1.73259296, 2.08146847, 2.80090151, 3.04446933, 
2.67647473, 3.87695509), state = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you once again for your help. I've edited my original post with a problem that came up as a result of this (or perhaps not a problem and just how the model works with constraints?).